# Fastest way of transfering small packages of data on the same computer

Tags: windows, ipc

I need to transfer small chunks of data (about 8 bytes) each time from one process to another process on the same computer.
What would you say is the fastest method to do so (sockets, shared memory, ...)?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Create and use a memory-mapped file in the two processes. Writing 8 bytes to memory and then reading them from there directly is the fastest.

Answer (score 1):

If you can create a window, use regular SendMessage() and put the data to wParam / lParam ( you don't need even WM_COPYDATA). This is a quick and efficient way of accomplishing your task. If you don't have a window, you can use PostThreadMessage() function

Answer (score 0):

Packets sent by UDP connection through the loopback interface are certainly very fast. This also always opens to you option to do the operation you request remotely. Shared memory would be probably faster, but not necesarilly easier to use.

Comment: UDP packets can be lost even on localhost (though rarely).